# fancy box youtube only 360p resolution is available

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, resolution

I'm getting my YouTube videos coming through just fine in FancyBox except that they will only allow 360p when all of the them are 1080p capable.  Can't really use it that way, as with 360p it's pretty much unwatchable.  I pulled the JS links to all the source directly so they are pretty much standard setups as in the demo.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you may be doing (because you are not posting any code), however fancybox is completely capable to show HD youtube videos.

You should be opening the video using the `embed` mode so your html should look (at least) like this :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/opj24KnzrWo?autoplay=1">Open youtube and select HD from options</a>
```

... and this works with a standard fancybox (v2.x) code

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

**Notice** that we are setting the `type` of content to `iframe` using the special class `fancybox.iframe` along with the normal class of our selector. Also notice that the video **WON'T** start in HD, that's the normal behavior, however you can change the resolution selecting  the youtube settings icon

[image]

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VGtjk/)**

Comment: Sorry about not adding code, I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't a bug or glitch that was known.  I was not using the iframe but instead using the media helper (I guess media is one of the helper functions).  here's a sample: 

<a class="fancybox-media" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBTUimPA96g"><img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/WBTUimPA96g/default.jpg" />

The version is 2.1.5

Comment: Ok, so under further review, replaing the "watch?v=" with embed actually allows the Resolution settings to come through.  Thanks for the help, I probably never would have picked up on that as the default demo code works without that change.  Can the recommended resolution be passed through the link that way?  Say if I wanted a minimum of 480p?

Comment: @portcitytech: if you go to http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples ==> extended functionality ==> media helper ==> the youtube sample uses the `watch?v=` format (which the media helper converts to iframe) and that demos shows the video at 480p resolution in my case. Remember, youtube will try to determine the bandwidth available and stream the video in the best resolution possible according to it.

Comment: This might have been just a glitch.  I started over and began again with the original code and all the resolutions came through.  I do believe though that your way of doing this is the better way, so I'll try going that route and see where I end up.  I marked your answer as correct.  Thanks very much for the assist.